# Newbie jQuery question, creating DOM elements on the fly

Tags: jquery

In the following jQuery snippet, why does the foo2 object have no elements? My alert shows me that foo1 does contain DOM elements. Shouldn't find("*") then just return what is effectively a clone of foo1?

```
var foo1 = $("<div id='content'>HAGGIS</div>");  
var foo2 = foo1.find("*");

alert("foo1("+foo1.length+"): "+$('<div>').append(foo1.clone()).remove().html()  
    + "\n\n" +  
      "foo2("+foo2.length+"): "+$('<div>').append(foo2.clone()).remove().html());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation about [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> **Description:** Get the *descendants* of
>   each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a
>   selector.

`foo1` has no descendants.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be simple. You were first to reply so yours gets marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

`foo2` has no elements because the selector is for all children of `foo1`, which has no child elements, just a text node.

Comment: @richb How did Gaby get it first when my answer was 3 minutes earlier (and [Reigel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404707/newbie-jquery-question-creating-dom-elements-on-the-fly/4404738#4404738) was 2 minutes earlier)?

Comment: because I am an idiot. Sorry. I got confused about who answered first. All three answers were good. Should I change it? What's the etiquette here?

Comment: @richb It is up to you. If you don't want to change the accepted answer, you should vote up our answers :)

Answer (score 1):

No, if I understand correctly your question, then I'd say that `find()` will look for the children. That is why `foo2.length` will give you 0. If you want the clone of `foo1` then `var foo2 = foo1.clone();` would be the right one.